# WordPress Plugin Error for Options Page

Tags: wordpress

A day ago, I started work on a WordPress plugin. I've never done any of this before (but know PHP and JavaScript), so I followed someone's tutorial. I got as far as being able to see my plugin in WP and even displaying a plugin option under "Settings."

Now I'm stuck. I want to add an Options page, and I followed the tutorial to a "T" before I realized it was a bit outdated (2009). So could anyone point out to me why my code does result in an error, when I want to access the Options page?

The error states: You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.

Here's my barebones WP plugin code:

```
<?php
    /*
    Plugin Name: OneClickReloadImageShow
    Plugin URI: http://www.blahblahblah.com
    Description: Plugin for displaying one image at a time and refreshing URL on clicking next or back buttons
    Author: Me
    Version: 1.0
    Author URI: http://www.blahblahblah.com
    */
?>

<?php

    function oneclickreloadimageshow_admin() {
        include('oneclickreloadimageshow_import_admin.php');
    }

    function oneclickreloadimageshow_admin_actions() {
        add_options_page("OCR Image Show", "OCR Image Show", 1, "OCR Image Show", "oneclickreloadimageshow_admin");
    }

    // THIS WORKS
    add_action('admin_menu', 'oneclickreloadimageshow_admin_actions');

?>
```

Any ideas? More importantly, does anyone know of any good WP plugin tutorials for a simple plugin?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your Capability value is not correct. Also, the slug should not contain spaces in it.

The function of add_option_page() takes the following parameters:

**add_options_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function);**

1. **Page Title** - (string) (required) The text to be displayed in the title tags of the page when the menu is selected
2. **Menu Title** - (string) (required) The text to be used for the menu.
3. **Capability** - (string) (required) The [capability](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Capabilities) required for this menu to be displayed to the user.
4. **Menu Slug** - (string) (required) The slug name to refer to this menu by (should be unique for this menu).
5. **Callback Function** - (callback) (optional) The function to be called to output the content for this page.

An example that can be used for reference,

```
add_options_page("OCR Image Show", "OCR Image Show", 'activate_plugins', "ocr-image-show", "oneclickreloadimageshow_admin");
```

Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_options_page